# Mysql query for donation is giving accurate sum but not displaying all events

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display donation data in following way where all donations' total will display under each donator.

```
Johnny Cruz
    Charity: Event 001 | Amount: US$ 100    
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$  30    
    Charity: Event 003 | Amount: US$  90            
                         Total : US$ 220

Mike Polo
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 200    
    Charity: Event 004 | Amount: US$ 125    
                         Total : US$ 325

Donald Thomas
    Charity: Event 005 | Amount: US$  75   
                         Total : US$  75 

Thomas Stain
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 125
    Charity: Event 003 | Amount: US$  85  
                         Total : US$ 210
```

This is the query that I am using currently.

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_donation_per_donator FROM tr_donation WHERE ngopkid=1  GROUP BY donator ORDER BY donator ASC, event ASC
```

Above query is giving me result as I mentioned below. It's giving correct sum of donations for each donator but displaying only one event. What change I need to do in query to get result like above sample I mentioned? Please help.

```
Johnny Cruz
    Charity: Event 001 | Amount: US$ 100    
                         Total : US$ 220

Mike Polo
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 200    
                         Total : US$ 325

Donald Thomas
    Charity: Event 005 | Amount: US$  75   
                         Total : US$  75 

Thomas Stain
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 125
                         Total : US$ 210
```

Here is table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tr_donation` (
  `pkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ngopkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `donator` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `eventpkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `event` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amount` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postdate` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

--- EDIT ---

IF I use below query, it is giving result in following way.

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_donation_per_donator FROM tr_donation WHERE ngopkid=1  GROUP BY donator, event ORDER BY donator ASC, event ASC

Johnny Cruz
    Charity: Event 001 | Amount: US$ 100
                         Total : US$ 100

    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$  30    
                         Total : US$  30

    Charity: Event 003 | Amount: US$  90            
                         Total : US$  90

Mike Polo
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 200
                         Total : US$ 200

    Charity: Event 004 | Amount: US$ 125    
                         Total : US$ 125

Donald Thomas
    Charity: Event 005 | Amount: US$  75   
                         Total : US$  75 

Thomas Stain
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 125
                         Total : US$ 125

    Charity: Event 003 | Amount: US$  85  
                         Total : US$  85
```

Comment: GROUP BY donator, event (but then you have to sum your row amounts to get the total amount: SUM(amount) AS total_donation_per_donator_event)

Comment: it's displaying all events but sum is also split for each event. I am editing my answer to show you result if I GROUP BY donator, event

Comment: But you can do the addition in your PHP script.

Comment: Yes, that may work but i need to show data in descending order of donation sum (highest amount first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL 'WITH ROLLUP'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

From the documentation:

> The GROUP BY clause permits a WITH ROLLUP modifier that causes extra
>   rows to be added to the summary output. These rows represent
>   higher-level (or super-aggregate) summary operations.

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year;
+------+-------------+
| year | SUM(profit) |
+------+-------------+
| 2000 |        4525 |
| 2001 |        3010 |
+------+-------------+

mysql> SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP;
+------+-------------+
| year | SUM(profit) |
+------+-------------+
| 2000 |        4525 |
| 2001 |        3010 |
| NULL |        7535 |
+------+-------------+
```

Read the doc for more information

This is the SQLFiddle of what I meant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/636141/8

Comment: Can you please create a sqlfiddle of your query and share the link, so that i can check.

Comment: my php programming was quite different but now it is displaying properly. Thank you...

Comment: How can i use ORDER BY in mysql query? please let me know.

Comment: GROUP BY automatically orders by the column mentioned in GROUP BY clause. But if you want to order in other way, the use ORDER BY <column-name> at the end of the query.

Comment: It's giving this error if I use ORDER BY at end of query - "Invalid query: Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY" ... I want to sort in way so highest amount donator will display first... rest of things are working fine so please help....

Comment: From the documentation: When you use ROLLUP, you cannot also use an ORDER BY clause to sort the results. In other words, ROLLUP and ORDER BY are mutually exclusive. However, you still have some control over sort order. GROUP BY in MySQL sorts results, and you can use explicit ASC and DESC keywords with columns named in the GROUP BY list to specify sort order for individual columns

Comment: Yes, ASC / DESC works with GROUP BY but I want to sort records so highest amount donator will display first. How can I do this?